# Insert swedish characters to opencart tables

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I just created a script to import a given file (csv) to opencart. The remote server transmits the data as iso-8859-1 and opencart uses utf8_bin collaction as default.

My problem is, that the script, where default echo statements show the desired output without problems or weird characters, doesn't submits the data to the database without messing up the special swedish characters.

Am example would be the word:  VÃƒÂ¤rmepump
This definately shouldn't look like that.

Any idea what exactly could fail? I already tried to add the SET NAMES 'utf8' query but it didn't help.

Comment: Needs more info. Can you show some code? At which point goes the code break?

Comment: Hey, actually the code doesn't break at all. All products are imported but with casual echo statements of the query, everything looks great and after running the query the characters in MySQL are broken.

The query to import the description and name:
`$sql_ins_prod_name = "insert into {$tbl_prefix}product_description set `product_id`=".$tmp_prod_id.", `language_id`=".$language_id.", `name`='".trim($prod_data[5])."', `description`='" . $prod_data[6]. "', `meta_description`='', `meta_keyword`=''";`

Comment: So the source data is iso-8859-1? Have you tried passing the string through [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/utf8_encode) before inserting it into the database?

Comment: Hey, yes everything gets utf8 encoded before processing. Many characters look good then, but sadly not all of them.

Comment: Do you validate the input encoding precisely? Which is the ***exact*** and ***correct*** input encoding?

Comment: File gets downloaded via file() as iso-8859-1 and then each row of the file gets encoded via utf8_encode() to utf8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the data is utf8 encoded, my guess would be there's some issue either in the database or in the database connection. Here's a few debugging tips for you.

**MySQL database and table character sets/collations** (from command line)

```
mysql -u [youruser] [yourdatabase] -p
mysql> SHOW CREATE DATABASE [yourdatabase];
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE [yourtable];
```

Everything should be utf8.

**MySQL database connection** (from PHP script)

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    error_log(print_r($row, true));
}
```

Everything should be utf8 here as well.

**EDIT:** Your string is in fact encoded twice. Running a simple

```
echo utf8_decode(utf8_decode('VÃƒÂ¤rmepump'))."\n";
```

in an ANSI-encoded PHP file outputs the expected "Värmepump". Make sure you encode your data only once.

Comment: Thanks! Several entries are latin1 there (connection part). Can you quickly say me how to change all of them to utf8?

Comment: @TheReaper: `SET NAMES utf8` after the connection is established should do the trick, but you mentioned you've already tried that? If you can change the MySQL configuration files (non-shared environment) and no other applications on the server are affected, you may want to change the settings in the configuration file (usually `my.cnf`). Relevant manual entries [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html).

Comment: Hey, okay I tried both. Sadly, it still doesn't work as expected. All values are utf8 now. I will may try to retrieve the file with the data using curl and hope this will do the trick.

Comment: @TheReaper: The data is double encoded somehow. See my edited answer.

Comment: Okay somehow php seems to download the file as utf8 so now it mostly worked. Just rarely one word got a problem but I guess that isn't the fault of the importer then. Thank you!